# Как сделать выбор слова в тексте?

Tags: java, android

Как можно вывести текст, и при касании одного слово какое-то действие делалось.

Сначала думал recyclerview горизонтальный или gridview таблица получится  не подходит/

Нужно будет длинные тексты в список выводить , listview тоже не сможет элементы в виде текста вывести.

Получается нужно textview вывести но как обработать клик по тексту и узнать какое слово было нажато.

Какие есть догадки? в englishcentral есть такое

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сделать при помощи `EditText` у которого не будет возможности редактирования текста:

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/edittext"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:editable="false"/>
```

Дальше мы длинным нажатием можем выбрать слово:

```
EditText edit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext);
OnLongClickListener lc = new OnClickListener(){

     @Override
     public boolean onLongClick(View view){

    int selection_start = edit.getSelectionStart();
    int selection_end = edit.getSelectionEnd();

    String copy = edit.getText().toString().subString(selection_start, selection_end);

    ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE); 

    clipboard.setText(copy);
    return false;
    }
 };

 edit.setOnLongClickListener(lc);
```

Вот есть подобные обсуждения [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8612652/select-a-word-on-a-tap-in-textview-edittext), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843596/android-highlight-a-word-in-a-textview) и [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475742/selecting-one-word-in-a-textview-in-android) из которых можно почерпнуть дополнительную информацию.

Comment: все спасибо сколько пыхтел по https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8612652/select-a-word-on-a-tap-in-textview-edittext ссылке смог все таки полностью решить проблему